# Why am I getting Error creating bean with name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-09T10:35:28.576+03:00 ERROR 15136 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productApi' defined in file [C:\Users\erayn\eclipse-workspace\shopping-app\target\classes\com\eray\shoppingapp\product\api\ProductApi.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productService' defined in file [C:\Users\erayn\eclipse-workspace\shopping-app\target\classes\com\eray\shoppingapp\product\service\ProductService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productEsRepository' defined in com.eray.shoppingapp.product.repository.es.ProductEsRepository defined in @EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories declared on ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.eray.shoppingapp.ShoppingAppApplication.main(ShoppingAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService' defined in file [C:\Users\erayn\eclipse-workspace\shopping-app\target\classes\com\eray\shoppingapp\product\service\ProductService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productEsRepository' defined in com.eray.shoppingapp.product.repository.es.ProductEsRepository defined in @EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories declared on ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productEsRepository' defined in com.eray.shoppingapp.product.repository.es.ProductEsRepository defined in @EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories declared on ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:536) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:89) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:100) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$27(Flux.java:7088) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$MonoCompletionStageSubscription.apply(MonoCompletionStage.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$MonoCompletionStageSubscription.apply(MonoCompletionStage.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162) ~[na:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport$1.onFailure(RestClientTransport.java:179) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onDefinitiveFailure(RestClient.java:684) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.failed(RestClient.java:422) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.1.jar:8.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.executionFailed(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:101) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:432) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:87) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:40) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository.createIndexAndMappingIfNeeded(SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository.java:68) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository.java:60) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:210) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:536) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:89) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Repository

```
   public interface ProductEsRepository extends ReactiveElasticsearchRepository<ProductEs, String> {
}
```

Controller

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/products")
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class ProductApi {
        private final ProductService productService;
        @GetMapping
        public Flux<ProductResponse> getAllProducts(){
            return this.productService.getAll();
        }
    }
```

Product Service

```
   @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class ProductService {
    
        private final ProductEsRepository productEsRepository;
        private final ProductRepository productRepository;
        private final ProductPriceService productPriceService;
        private final ProductDeliveryService productDeliveryService;
        private final ProductAmountService productAmountService;
        private final ProductImageService productImageService;
    
        public Flux<ProductResponse> getAll() {
            return this.productEsRepository.findAll().map(this::mapToDto);
        }
   
        private ProductResponse mapToDto(ProductEs item) {
            BigDecimal productPrice = this.productPriceService.getByMoneyType(item.getId(), MoneyTypes.USD);
           return ProductResponse.builder()
                    .price(productPrice)
                    .name(item.getName())
                    .features(item.getFeatures())
                    .id(item.getId())
                    .description(item.getDescription())
                    .deliveryIn(this.productDeliveryService.getDeliveryInfo(item.getId()))
                    .categoryId(item.getCategory().getId())
                    .available(this.productAmountService.getByProductId(item.getId()))
                    .freeDelivery(this.productDeliveryService.freeDeliveryCheck(item.getId(), productPrice))
                    .moneyType(MoneyTypes.USD)
                    .image(this.productImageService.getProductMainImage(item.getId()))
                    .seller(ProductSellerResponse.builder().id(item.getSeller().getId()).name(item.getSeller().getName()).build())
                    .build();
    
        }
    }
```

Dependency

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.eray</groupId>
        <artifactId>shopping-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>shopping-app</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Docker compose

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
    -  27017:27017
    environment:
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: eray123
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.5.0
    ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
    environment:
       discovery.type: single-node
```

Description
I added @Repository annotation but it didn't work, I changed elasticsearch version but it still didn't work

when i remove final keyword only this error remains

```
Error creating bean with name 'productEsRepository' defined in com.eray.shoppingapp.product.repository.es.ProductEsRepository defined in @EnableReactiveElasticsearchRepositories declared on ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleReactiveElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
```

i don't know what to do i upgraded elasticsearch version from 8.5.3 to 8.5.0 but the problem persists

Comment: Please don't post images but he errors stacktraces as code blocks. Your images don't show the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

You get a Connection closed error, that means Elasticsearch does not accept the connection from your application.

Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode, you'll need to make your Java application accept the certifivate for the HTTPS TLS connectio

For a local enviroment (and only for that!) you might want to disable the security, there's some informaiton here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-elasticserach-8-via-docker-without-certificate/303617

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I followed your advice but still getting the same error @PJ.Meisch

Comment: Can you connect for example with `curl https://localhost:9200`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is at the constructor of the ProductService class, you can try using @Autowired annotation on the repository fields in the ProductService class and also use a @NoArgsConstructor annotation on the ProductService class. Something like this

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductEsRepository productEsRepository;
    @Autowired        
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductPriceService productPriceService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductDeliveryService productDeliveryService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductAmountService productAmountService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductImageService productImageService;

    public Flux<ProductResponse> getAll() {
        return this.productEsRepository.findAll().map(this::mapToDto);
    }

    private ProductResponse mapToDto(ProductEs item) {
        BigDecimal productPrice = this.productPriceService.getByMoneyType(item.getId(), MoneyTypes.USD);
       return ProductResponse.builder()
                .price(productPrice)
                .name(item.getName())
                .features(item.getFeatures())
                .id(item.getId())
                .description(item.getDescription())
                .deliveryIn(this.productDeliveryService.getDeliveryInfo(item.getId()))
                .categoryId(item.getCategory().getId())
                .available(this.productAmountService.getByProductId(item.getId()))
                .freeDelivery(this.productDeliveryService.freeDeliveryCheck(item.getId(), productPrice))
                .moneyType(MoneyTypes.USD)
                .image(this.productImageService.getProductMainImage(item.getId()))
                .seller(ProductSellerResponse.builder().id(item.getSeller().getId()).name(item.getSeller().getName()).build())
                .build();

    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.